# Android Studio Login Form

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to make a login form:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    tv.setClickable(true);
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class));
        }
});

username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Uname);
password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Pword);
party=username.getText().toString();
p2=password.getText().toString();
ok=(Button)findViewById(.id.btnLogin);

ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(party.isEmpty() && p2.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if(!party.isEmpty() && !p2.isEmpty()){
            db.execSQL("select * from Students where Name='"+party+"'and Password='"+p2+"'");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class));
        }
    }
});
```

When i enter the username and password the toast i make to show "empty fields" whenever i click login it says empty fields:

Comment: it stuck here f(party.isEmpty() && p2.isEmpty()){

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return;

Comment: What the hell is this formatting? Even braces don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with length

```
if(party.toString().trim().length < 0 && p2.toString().trim().length < 0){

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return;

}else {

db.execSQL("select * from Students where Name='"+party+"'and Password='"+p2+"'");

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class));

}
```

Comment: sorry i'm new here xD

Answer (score 0):

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Uname);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pword);

party = username.getText().toString();
p2 = password.getText().toString();


ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (party.equals("") || p2.equals("")) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            db.execSQL("select * from Students where Name='" + party + "'and Password='" + p2 + "'");

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class));

        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this work for me.

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(party) || TextUtils.isEmpty(p2)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else

    {
        db.execSQL("select * from Students where Name='" + party + "'and Password='" + p2 + "'");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class));
    }
```